# Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS from a NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, iphone-sdk-3.0, exc-bad-access

I had a EXC_BAD_ACCESS message in my console. I read about the environment variables NSZombieEnabled and MallocStackLoggingNoCompact on [this site](http://coderslike.us/2009/05/05/finding-freeddeallocated-instances-of-objects/). I created my environment variables: **NSZombieEnabled = YES**  and **MallocStackLoggingNoCompact = 1**. In the console, I saw

> 2010-03-01 19:13:46.924
>   CruzNomad[7952:207] *** -[CFString
>   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]:
>   message sent to deallocated instance
>   0x58448e0

Then at the (gdb) prompt, I did **info malloc-history 0x58448e0**, which gave me:

```
Alloc: Block address: 0x058448e0 length: 64
Stack - pthread: 0xa0b33500 number of frames: 25
    0: 0x98e089bc in malloc_zone_malloc
    1: 0x21516aa in _CFRuntimeCreateInstance
    2: 0x2152bf8 in __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3
    3: 0x21567d9 in CFStringCreateCopy
    4: 0x21742fc in _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux
    5: 0xdb546 in -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]
    6: 0xdb4d8 in +[NSString stringWithFormat:]
    7: 0x23aa3 in -[BuisnessCardViewController viewDidLoad] at /Users/.../Classes/BuisnessCardViewController.m:85
    8: 0x3d6796 in -[UIViewController view]
    9: 0x347b4 in -[gm_menuViewController btn5_Pressed:] at /Users/.../Classes/menuViewController.m:535
   10: 0x357459 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
   11: 0x3baba2 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
   12: 0x3bcdc3 in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
   13: 0x3bbb0f in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
   14: 0x370e33 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
   15: 0x35a81c in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
   16: 0x3610b5 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
   17: 0x2984ed1 in PurpleEventCallback
   18: 0x2197b80 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
   19: 0x2196c48 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
   20: 0x298378d in GSEventRunModal
   21: 0x2983852 in GSEventRun
   22: 0x362003 in UIApplicationMain
   23: 0x2c8c in main at /Users/.../source/main.m:14
   24: 0x2bfa in start
```

Line 7 says the problem was in line 85 of BuisnessCardViewController.m. That line is here:

```
fullAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", fullAddress, myString];
```

I'm appending the contents of **fullAddress** and **myString** and storing it back in **fullAddress**.

If I'm interpreting this correctly, it appears that after this line, **fullAddress** is deallocated. When I drop a breakpoint and hover over the variable, its value says "out of scope."

**fullAddress** works later in this method. I use it to send to send to Google for reverse geocoding in line 164 of the same method.

```
NSString    *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", [fullAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Even here, it says "out of scope." I'm stumped...any advice??

Thanks!

Thomas

Comment: Can you post a bit more context? If it says the variable went out of scope, can we see the whole scope?

Comment: Are you using `fullAddress` or `myString` anywhere else?

Comment: Also, just in case it was an accident, you've misspelled Business as Buisness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases this happens when you don't retain an attribute which is object and send late messages to it in other methods, late.

So, where some strings are initialized try:

```
[fullAddress retain];
```

or

```
[myString retain];
```

depending which one is initialized in other method.

Comment: If the response is not totally clear, excuse me for my language please and write bellow comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried appending string with format?**

```
fullAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", fullAddress, myString];
```

with:

```
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingFormat:(NSString *)format ...
```

like this:

```
[fullAddress stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", myString];
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, folks. And no, I didn't realize Business was spelled wrong. 

@dreamlax - I didn't write that class (thankfully lol) :-)...I'm just working on specific features. Thanks for pointing it out though! 

I figured out my problem. Since stringWithFormat returns an autoreleased object, I just retained it right after I used it for the first time earlier in the method.

[fullAddress retain];

did the trick (as I now see mxg has suggested).
Once again, thanks everybody!
-Thomas